# What is a simple protocol for staining cells in suspension?

Tags: molecular-biology, lab-techniques, microscopy

I am an engineering student studying how electric fields affect cells, specifically the phenomena of electroporation in living cells.

I know that electroporation is widely used for introducing genes into cells, but running a full transfection experiment is not so feasible in the lab I am working in.

My question is:

If I want to demonstrate the principle of electroporation, i.e. that cells open up and intake substances from the environment, by using some kind of a dye which i can later visualize, what could be a good model for this type of experiment? Specifically - what dye, what cells could be used for this?

Comment: Are we talking about mammalian cells or bacteria?

Comment: That's probably part of his question ;)

Answer (score 1):

**You will get a lot of false-positives using the following method, and a real transfection of a fluorescent protein is always the way to go, because then you will prove that the transfection was really successful.**

That said, you could try to use [DAPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DAPI), followed by fluorescence microscopy or flow cytometry. DAPI is a very bright stain for DNA and cannot pass an intact cell membrane. If the cell membrane is disrupted, e. g. by necrosis, DAPI will enter the cell. I have never seen anyone trying to prove electroporation this way, but it will be worth a try. It could be that the time is too short for DAPI to enter the cell, so you'd need to tweak your setup.

I'd try the following: Prepare a cell solution with DAPI (something like 5 µM concentration should do). Split the solution into two electroporation cuvettes, perform the electroporation with one cuvette, leave the second one untouched as a control. After the electroporation, analyse the samples MOMENTARILY (means: within a few minutes) using a flow cytometer (if possible).

As for the cells, you could use anything. I suggest eukaryotic cells because they are more easy to visualize than bacteria. However, you would need a laminar flow hood for aseptic handling of cells. In theory you could also use bacteria, which are more easy to handle, but I'm not experienced with immunofluorescence in bacteria.